# Taking linearly independent vectors to construct a linear functional that satisfies certain properties

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let, $(X,||.||)$ be a normed space  and let $v_1$ and $v_2$ be two linearly independent vectors in $X$. Is there any way to define a bounded linear functional $\phi:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
such that,
$$\phi(v_i) = i^2||v_i||,$$
where
$$||\phi||_{\infty} \ge 5?$$
I know you can define a $V = \textrm{span}\{v_1,v_2 \}$ such that $\phi:V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\phi(c_1v_1 + c_2v_2) = c_1||x_1|| + 4c_2||x_2||.$
And then use the Hahn-Banach Theorem to obtain a  bounded linear functional $\phi':X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies:
$$\phi'(v_i) = i^2||v_i||,$$
but I'm having a hard time showing that:
$$||\phi'||_{\infty} \ge 5?$$

I have been told that this is possible or is it not? Do I need to specify extra vectors or? Thanks.

Comment: If $X$ is just a vector space there is no notion of continuous or bounded linear functionals.

Comment: What does $\|\phi\|_\infty$ mean exactly? Is that just the operator norm corresponding to the norm on $X$? Or does the $\infty$ have some kind of meaning that I'm missing?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy fixed that.

Comment: @TheoBendit 

Yes, the operator norm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily. If $X = \Bbb{R}^2$ under the $1$-norm, with $v_1 = (1, 0)$ and $v_2 = (0, 1)$, then we would have
$$\phi(a, b) = a + 4b.$$
If $\|(a, b)\| \le 1$, then $|a| + |b| \le 1$, which implies $a \le 1$ and $b \le 1$. For such $(a, b)$, we have
$$\phi(a, b) = a + 4b \le 1 + 4 \cdot 1 = 5.$$
Hence $\|\phi\| \le 5$. By assumption, $\|\phi\| = 5$, and since we are in finite-dimensions, we can find $(a, b)$ such that $\|(a, b)\| \le 1$ and $\phi(a, b) = 5$. This implies equalities in each of the above inequalities, hence $a = b = 1$. But, $(1, 1)$ does not have norm $1$. Thus, we have a contradiction: there is no such $\phi$ in $\Bbb{R}^2$ under the $1$-norm.

Comment: I see, thanks. I should have used a concrete example in order to see it as not possible. Thanks.